# Access Corev15.css file of Online SharePoint Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, style

As far as my understanding, In SharePoint on-premise version of SharePoint corev15.css file is located at **c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\ _layouts\15\1036\styles\corev15.css** path in local system.

But I was trying to find corev15.css file in office 365 in SharePoint online, and I could not find this file in any folder. I can check this file in browser by entering correct URL in browser, But I can not make any change as far as I could not open it by physical location.

One of the my office mate advice me to copy the content of corev15.css file into another file and upload it to style Library and overwrite all css again. Is it correct way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to add some customization to your current css?
If yes, then it's better to create new css with your additional css settings and upload it into **Site Asset**. And go to **Site Master Page Settings** -> **Alternate CSS URL** -> choose your uploaded css -> **OK**

You dont have to copy content of corev15.css. It will added automatically into your current css

**EDITED**

you can go to http://yoursite/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css to see your corev15.css

Comment: Actually I was to remove some style attributes from corev15.css. which is not possible by adding any other css. Another approach is I can remove by jquery. But I don't think it is proper way.

Comment: Yes. I can just see css file code. But I can not change it unless and until I don't find physical file. I want to remove some css code from corev15.css

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers to find some physical file you can Open File In Explorer from your SharePoint Online. And then you search based on filename. You will find it